# Form onchange event not calling when drop 'n drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I created a form with the option to either 'drag and drop', or 'click to upload' a file. When either of the 2 happens, I want it to trigger an action.

I used the `onchange` event to trigger an action when a value in the form changes.

```
$("#uploadform").on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("Something Changed");
});
```

That only gets triggered when I 'click to upload' a file. When I 'drag 'n drop' a file, the event doesn't get triggered.

How can I trigger the same event when I 'click to upload' or 'drag 'n drop' happens?

Please post answers in JQuery.

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#uploadform").on('change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("Something Changed");
    });

    $('#browseFileDiv').click(function (e) {
        $(this).find('input[type="file"]').click();
    });
    $('#browseFileDiv input').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });



    // Setup Drag 'n Drop

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    function handleDragOver(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    }

    var dropZone = document.getElementById('browseFileDiv');
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
});
```

```css
#browseFileDiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
#browseFileDiv > input {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="uploadform">
    <div id="browseFileDiv">
        <input id="openFile" name="img" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can try to get the value on change if length > 0 run the code have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying I should remove the onchange event and instead do `if length > 0`?

Comment: no inside on change event do the if condition

Comment: But if it doesn't run at all when I drag and drop, why would it run with an if statement?

Comment: your click triggers the input but your change does big difference

Comment: I understand, but I want the same action to be triggered by drag 'n drop and click to upload a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Trying to implement the `change` and `drop` listener properly.

```js
$("#uploadform").on('change drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert("Something Changed");
});

// No longer need for `drop` event listener on the `dropZone` element.
// In particular DO NOT stop propagation, otherwise the form will not receive it.
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jytL8heo/2/

---

A workaround would be to simply fire the `"change"` event manually on drop.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    // Manually fire the change event.
    $("#uploadform").trigger("change");

    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jytL8heo/1/

Comment: I guess because 1) you stop event propagation, so the form will not receive it, and 2) the drag'n'drop creates a `drop` event, not a `change`. Let's try doing it properly, I will edit the answer and demo.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The way I accessed the 'click to upload' file was like this: `new FormData($(this)[0]);`. For some reason it's not working with the 'drag 'n drop'. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Indeed the `drop` event stores associated files differently. First answer to this question should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261989/html5-javascript-drag-and-drop-file-from-external-window-windows-explorer