# Detect when a file is dragged onto a file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this code to detect when a user clicks a file input to upload a file.

```
$('input:file').click(function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

I discovered that many users are dragging files onto the file input to upload a file, and this is not triggering when that happens. I considered `mouseover`, perhaps in combination with `mouseup`, but I'm not sure how I would know if the user was holding a file while doing that.

To clarify, I do not need help implementing drag and drop. Also, if possible I want to keep using the file input, and not use a a solution involving dropping onto other elements such as a div. I want the drop to remain on the actual file input.

How can I detect a file being dragged on a file input so that I can react to it?

Comment: Have you tried to get the position of the pointer by using `mousemove()` ? https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Comment: Try this page http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: @GôTô that is how to implement dragging on an element. Users are not dragging an element, they are dragging an off browser file, so this doesn't seem to be what I need. Also, w3schools is just awful, incomplete, and often misleading.

Comment: @Goose the `drop` event is relevant even in this case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261989/html5-javascript-drag-and-drop-file-from-external-window-windows-explorer

Comment: @GôTô, My file input isn't set up with javascript to allow drag and drop, it's just default browser behavior. Maybe you can post an answer showing how to apply it in my case, because currently I'm not sure what to take from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can react to browser native drag events like `dragenter` and `dragleave`

```
container.addEventListener("dragenter", this.dragenter, true);
container.addEventListener("dragleave", this.dragleave, true);
```

So you need to define only areas you want to monitor when drag occurs and your actions on this events.

Comment: Looks like what I need, but my attempt at it did not work, see my updated question to see how I tried to apply it.

Comment: Seems it works on this fiddle. Please recheck https://jsfiddle.net/3fnatryv/
AddEventListener is native browser event so you need to get DOM element from jQuery search. I use first element [0]

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Note on the jsfiddle, because of multiple inputs, I had foreach it like so. https://jsfiddle.net/3fnatryv/1/

Answer (score 0):

I saw that when I drag a file on an input, without any Javascript (except "change" event), I managed to do it.